# hive read map value

Tags: hive

Here is my data in a file which i have successfully loaded into a table test and successfully get the data for:

```
Select * from test;



Name    ph        category

Name1    ph1    {"type":1000,"color":200,"shape":610}
Name2    ph2    {"type":2000,"color":200,"shape":150}
Name3    ph3    {"type":3000,"color":700,"shape":167}
```

But when i execute this query:

```
select category["type"] from test;
```

I get null values;

Please help.
Thanks
Sai

Comment: Could you paste here 'describe test;' output ?

Answer (score 6):

use this: 
`select test.category["type"] from test;`

Comment: Will fail if type is not in the map

Comment: Use `str_to_map` to convert string to map type

Answer (score 1):

The null check is missing in your query

`SELECT category["type"] 
 FROM test 
 WHERE category["type"] IS NOT NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

I know its a very late to answer..

I faced the same issue, When i created the map, for the key, i manually added the double-quotes("), before and after the key, that was the issue. So if you have something similar in your code, remove it and try to run. It may fix the issue.